# No SSH conncetion to remote pi from WAN

Tags: networking, ssh

I have a pi on a remote location, every now and then the connection is lost.
I keep on asking somebody on the pi network to log into it using ssh and restart networking and only then it works. I was very specific that they do not reboot the pi. So networking works localy.
I also asked to ping an google.com from the pi and it did not work, but pinging 8.8.8.8 of google does work. So I thought it was a DNS issue, so I codded 8.8.8.8 in resolv.conf and things worked for a while but now again I have no connection anymore. 
I'm using static IP on the pi.
How can I be sure that it is still a DNS problem or smth else? is the kind of issues logged somewhere in /var/logs?

I also noticed that resolv.conf is regenerated...just like in ubuntu...

Comment: Have you tried ssh into a linux box from wan other than the pi? you would do this to test if the issue is the pi or not. could be your router/switch or modem or dsl router/modem. or the isp is doing something that messes up ssh.

Comment: Unfort. I do not have any other linux machine on that network. That would have helped!

Answer (score 1):

Edit the `/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/base` (or the head file ) and add any manually added dns server. resolvconf will generate the resolve.conf based on that info.

Why is the dns is disappearing is strange, are your dhcp working fine?

You can also try installing dnsmasq, to bypass the resolvconf weirdness. Do `apt-get install dnsmasq` and then restart the network. You may need to add the resolvers to dnsmasq, if there is none in `/etc/resolv.conf`

Comment: /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/base does not exist on my pi! I dont use dhcp, maybe thats why?

Comment: check if you have resolvconf... if not, what is changing the resolv.conf? try to check that. look at the modify time to see if its a cron, the owner, who have permissions, etc